# Find all real solutions to the equation $4x^2 - 40[x] + 51 = 0$, where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I got this problem from an exercise in the Greatest Integer Function ,

Find all real solutions to the equation $4x^2 - 40[x] + 51 = 0$, where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function of $x$.

I am thinking that the solution of it will be pretty straightforward (note that I still do not know an actual solution of this) , since i can see that the LHS (Left - Hand Side) is congruent to 3 (mod 4) , whereas the RHS (Right - Hand Side) is congruent to 0 (mod 4) . Since that is not possible , I conclude there are no solutions .

Am i doing some errors or am i missing something ? Or is my answer and my proof correct ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You assumed $x$ is an integer, but the question asks for *real* solutions

Comment: But, even if x is a real number , the part 4x^2 - 40[x] can be written as 4(x^2 - 10[x]) which is divisible by 4 and since 51 is congruent to 3 (mod 4) , so I conclude that the LHS is congruent to 3 mod 4

Comment: Your reasoning would suggest that $4a\equiv 0\mod a$, for all real $a$. But what happens if $a=0,5$ for instance? Is it still $0$ mod $4$?

Comment: How did u get 4a ≡ 0 mod a

Comment: Upps, I meant $4a\equiv 0\mod 4$

Comment: Yeah , and that is true for every real a right?

Comment: Prove it yourself with $a=0,5$. Does it work? Does it make sense to define modular arithmetic for integer numbers? For reals?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva, $0,5$ is not universally understood. I suggest writing it as $\frac12$ instead.

Comment: Gouri, your argument -- if it was valid -- could be used to prove that the equation $4x^2-3=0$ has no real solutions...

Comment: Yeah , u are right , my argument is not valid , so can anyone suggest me some hints or solutions of this?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can solve this, and it [draws a nice graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%5E2-40*floor%28x%29%2B51%3D0) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$4x^2-40x+51=0\text{ or }4x^2-40(x-1)+51=0\implies1\le x<4\text{ or }6\le x<9$$

which bounds all possible solutions.

Now consider setting $\lfloor x\rfloor$ to be values between these points. We start with finding solutions at the lower end:

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=1\implies 4x^2-40+51=0\implies\text{no solution}$$

Then try the next:

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=2\implies4x^2-80+51=0\implies x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{29}}2$$

and since we have $\displaystyle\lfloor x\rfloor=2=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{29}}2\right\rfloor$, $\displaystyle x=\frac{\sqrt{29}}2$ is one solution.

Continue this way up to $\lfloor x\rfloor=8$ to find all real solutions.

Comment: I like your answer , I can understand how I had to use the greatest integer function

Comment: You have $50x$ in your first equation. Should that be $40x$? (Also, you seem to be assuming that $\lfloor x\rfloor=x$ or $x-1$, which is not true.)

Comment: @TonyK That was just a typo. And the point of the first part is to bound the roots (you can see that the quadratic formula is monotone in the constant coefficient, so $x-1\le\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$ suffices)

Comment: You have $50(x-1)$ in your first equation. Should that be $40(x-1)$?

Comment: @TonyK derp! xd

Answer (score 5):

$$\lfloor x\rfloor+1> x\geq \lfloor x\rfloor$$
$$\implies4\lfloor x\rfloor^2 - 32\lfloor x\rfloor + 55>4x^2 - 40\lfloor x\rfloor + 51=0\geq4\lfloor x\rfloor^2 - 40\lfloor x\rfloor + 51$$
$$\implies (2\lfloor x\rfloor-5)(2\lfloor x\rfloor-11)>0\ \text{and}\ (2\lfloor x\rfloor-3)(2\lfloor x\rfloor-17)\leq0$$
$$\implies \lfloor x\rfloor\in\{2,6,7,8\}\implies x\in\left\{\frac{\sqrt{29}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{189}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{229}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{269}}{2}\right\}$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, yes. Thanks, editing it.

Comment: +1 nice solution, those factored quite nicely.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, the question must have been created so that they factor nicely.